# Image not displayed when inserting and fetching from sql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, image, jdbc

This is the code to submit and retrieve the images from database, but the images are neither visible in database, nor in the jpg files (when I am fetching them). Can anybody tell me what the error is?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String sw = "";
    if(ae.getSource() == b1) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            // Insert image
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1","root","kanishkag");
            String INSERT_PICTURE = "insert into image values (?)";
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            byte blob[] = new byte[(byte)selectedFile.length()];
            fis.read(blob);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
            ps.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int) selectedFile.length());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
            ps.close();
            fis.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(""+e);
        }
    }
    else {
        try{
            // Retrieve image
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1","root","kanishkag");
            Statement smt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select pictures from image ");
            int i = 0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                OutputStream os = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                System.out.println("hiiiii");
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(800,600,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
                ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
                os = new FileOutputStream(new File("test1"+i+".jpg"));
                ImageOutputStream oss = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
                i++;
                int c = 0;
                while((c=iis.read())> -1) {
                    os.write(c);
                }
                ImageIO.write(bi, "test1"+i+".jpg", oss);
                os.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype in your mysql table.

Comment: can you try with setBlob()

Comment: can you please explain it with code?

Comment: in that case, do i need to remove the setBinarystream()?

Comment: yes replace             ps.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int) selectedFile.length());
 with ps.setBlob(1,fis);

Comment: showing exception - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V